# Mac: zsh: command not found: -s / (failed: redirect iOS backups to external hdd)

Tags: ios, macos, terminal, directory, backup

When I try to move my iOS backup folder (which does not yet have any backups) to my external hdd, the command line (on Mac) tells me that the command -s is not found.

This was the directory which I've tried to link the iTunes backups to:

```
user123@user123s-MacBook-Pro ~ % -s /Volumes/Personal/user123/iOSBackup/Old_Backup/ ~/Library/Application\ Support/MobileSync
zsh: command not found: -s
```

when I entered it manually instead of copy pasting it, it said that permission was denied, even though I had granted full disk access to the terminal app before for coding in vs code and such...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first problem is that you’re trying to execute `-s` rather than `ln -s`.

What is the goal of your `ln` operation? To symlink the folder called `Old_Backup` inside the `MobileSync` directory? That won’t work if your intention is that additional backups go to `Old_Backup`. You should symlink the `Old_Backup` directory to the location and name it originally had.